Caused by: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize Caused by: java.io.EOFException: null
I have a generic hibernate exception:
Caused by: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:243)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: null
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2736)

I have query which is causing this problem and I can manually run this in SQL tool and get correct result, so I know that query should be correct.
How to debug this issue and get more specific error?
@Edit
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCTS")
public class Products extends CommonProduct<StandardProduct> {
    private static final Set<ProductStatus> validStatesForApprover =
            ImmutableSet.of(ProductStatus.Approved, ProductStatus.Cancelled, ProductStatus.Delisted);

    @Ignore
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "products_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "products_seq", sequenceName = "products_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    protected Integer productId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "instrument", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @OrderBy("corpOrder")
    private Set<Action> actions = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @OrderBy("TicketId DESC")
    private Set<Ticket> Tickets = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @OrderBy("active DESC, date DESC, typeId DESC")
    private Set<State> states = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    @Column(name="save_to")
    private String saveTo = "Y";

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "parentProduct", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Attributes attributes;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<AlternativeCurrency> alternativeCurrency = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    @Ignore
    @Column(name="CREATED")
    private Calendar created;

    @Column(name="ARCHIVE")
    private Calendar archive;

    @Column(name="SERIES_ID")
    private String seriesId;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "MIRROR_ID")
    private Instrument mirrorProduct = null;

but I am asking about more generic solution than solution to my problem. Hibernate error is very broad and doesn't help at all.

Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with sufficient code to be able to replicate the problem. We cannot debug code that we cannot see.

I went with debugger into SerializableTypeDescriptor and SerializationHelper and were able to find school mistake - for one field I got:
@Column(name = "CALCULATION_ID")
private Calculation calculation;

instead of:
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "CALCULATION_ID")
private Calculation calculation;

in parent class. Without debugger it's really hard to find the issue, especially when class is big and is extending other class.
